# How to avoid resizing column and row when binded image is bigger than cell?

Tags: wpf, xaml, size, equals, divide

I have to divide my window into four equal parts. In second part there is an image which is downloaded from the database. This image should be fill to size of cell. Unfortunately when I open image than size is bigger tham this cell, this cell grows up. Is there any wat to block size of cell in grid? This is my row/cell definition:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
 <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
```

This is my Image control:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="DarkOrange">
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBlock Foreground="DarkOrange" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Photo"/>
     </GroupBox.Header>
     <Image Source="{Binding Item.photo}" Stretch="Fill"/>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: ScrollViewer is your friend.

Comment: Nay to ScrollViewer, just throw it in a `ViewBox` with Stretch to Fill and maybe even incorporate [SharedSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I  tried ViewBox but it changed nothing. Unfortunately I didn't use SharedSize, because I don't get it.

Comment: Well with your `*` declarations you're basically telling it that its children can take whatever space they need. You have to tell your `Grid` to restrict the size of each cell. Then your `ViewBox` will actually invoke and do what's it made to do and scale your image to the size required to fill the space it's provided.

Comment: Try setting `Stretch="UniformToFill"`